# Cron for AWS - Run every hour except between 10:30 and 12:30 on tuesdays

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-glue

I have a Glue job that runs at the beginning of every hour. The Cron expression for the trigger looks like this cron(0 * * * ? *).

However, for an two hours on every tuesdays, the destination redshift cluster goes down during it's maintenance window, And I'd rather not run the job then.

How do I specify the cron expression for "Run on the 0th minute of every hour everyday except between 10:30 and 12:30 on Tuesdays"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might have to just have two cronjobs one for tuesday, and one for other days

Tuesday: (0 0-10,13-23 * * 2)  https://crontab.guru/#0_0-10,13-23_*_*_2

Other days: (0 * * * 0-1,3-7) https://crontab.guru/#0_*_*_*_0-1,3-7

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I can have two separate triggers with two separate cron descriptions.
Thanks Banjo.